# python dictionary and prettytable module

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, prettytable

Need small help or at least point to right direction.
I am writing small function that should print content of a dict in the  prettytable format.

Here is code example:

```
head = ["HOSTNAME", "OS", "PROTOCOL"]

data = {
    'server1': ['ESXi', 'FC'],
    'server2': ['ESXi', 'FC'],
    'server3': ['ESXi', 'FC'],
}

def printify_table(header, data, align='c'):

    x = PrettyTable()
    x.field_names = header
    x.align = align

    for k, v in data.items():
        x.add_row([k, v[0], v[1]])
    print(x)


printify_table(head, data)
```

Result:
python x.py

```
+----------+------+----------+
| HOSTNAME |  OS  | PROTOCOL |
+----------+------+----------+
| server1  | ESXi |    FC    |
| server2  | ESXi |    FC    |
| server3  | ESXi |    FC    |
+----------+------+----------+
```

---

This works fine for now as I have static dict values.
No problem there!

***Issue| Problem :***
Now, what would be the pythonic approach to adjust code in case I face different number of  values for each key?

In case I come across something like this?

```
data = {
    'server1': ['ESXi'],
    'server2': ['ESXi', 'FC'],
    'server3': ['ESXi', 'FC','iSCI],
}
```

How yould you adjust below line?

```
  x.add_row([k, v[0], v[1]]
```

I tried with comprehension list but somehow I am struggling to incorporate it.
Any feedback appreciated.

Comment: Depending which python version you're using, you can use `[k, *v]` but how would that work for the fixed number of headings?

Comment: Thanks Holloway, its python 3.8 and *v is solving my (first) issue. So simple but very effective. Thanks once more. Yeah, heading problem would be next one :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `*` unpacking in lists.

```
>>> a = [3, 4, 5]
>>> b = [1, 2, *a]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

For your case, this would be `add_row([k, *v])`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for an excellent question, the world would be a better if people were to think more Pythonian. I think the snippet below will work:

```
v.extend(['']*(30-len(v)))
```

Insert it in your `for`-loop.